# extract particular directories from the set of directories

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0

i have a path dir called serverpath which is configurable.
eg.

```
serverpath=@"C:\AAA\New folder\";
```

in server path there are large number of directories. in following format:

```
serverpath\ID1\ID2\FileType\YYYY\MM\DD.MM.YYYY
i.e. C:\AAA\New folder\123\456\2017\01\01.01.2017
```

when i call

```
 Directory.EnumerateDirectories(serverpath, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

i get all the directories but i want only those path which are in the given format.

so far i have tries adding "??.??.????" pattern in the EnumerateDirectories method

```
Directory.EnumerateDirectories(serverpath, "??.??.????", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

but still i am getting path which are like this:

```
C:\AAA\New folder\123\456\pdf\2017\01 
C:\AAA\New folder\123\456\txt\2017\01
```

i only want path like these:

```
C:\AAA\New folder\123\456\pdf\2017\01\01.01.2017
C:\AAA\New folder\123\456\txt\2017\01\01.01.2017
```

and exclude all the other paths in the directory

any other way to do this other than counting slashes..?

Edit: is there any way to get directory path of the last folder in the directory? "01.01.2017" folders are the last folders in their respective directories.

Comment: It looks like it is the "." after the first "??" that is causing the problem - I played with similar folder structure in my debug folder which has multiple language subfolders & I got all two character folders (de,es, fr, ...) listed. When I changed the format of the final folder to 01_01_2017 & the search string to "??_??_????" - then I only got the required folder back.

Comment: thats not an option for me..i am not allowed to change the folder names.

Comment: Then it looks like you may need to do some post-processing as it appears to be how EnumerateDirectories works - though there is nothing in the documentation to say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string serverpath = @"C:\AAA\New folder\";

            Regex re = new Regex(@"\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}");
            var dirs = from dir in
                       Directory.EnumerateDirectories(serverpath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                       where re.IsMatch(dir)
                       select dir;
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work. Sorry if I have misunderstood - I am new to this.

```
\d = digit
{} = quantifier (of what is left of the quantifier)
. = any character (NOT OF ANY USE HERE)
\. = explicit dot
```